# Ряд Тейлора "Вывести на экран в виде таблицы значения функции"

Tags: python, ряды

Интервал от xнач до xкон с шагом dx и точность eps.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код, почему-то не работает с низкой точностью, хотя наоборот должно... Да и ряд Тейлора я не понимаю как делать.

```
import math

xn=float(input("Введите xнач : "))
xk=float(input("Введите xкон : "))
while True:
    dx=float(input("Введите шаг (от 0 до 2): "))
    if (dx>0) and (dx<=2):
       break
Eps = float(input("Введите точность  (Eps): "))
print('\nФункция: cos(x) \nТочность (Eps): %.3f\nШаг (dx): %.3f\nИнтервал: [%.f, %.f]' % (Eps, dx, xn, xk))
print('\n\n|\tВычисление значений ряда Тейлора\t\n----------------------------------------------')
print ('|tx   |    f(x)\t| Кол-во эл-ов (n) |\n-------------------------------------------------')
xn = abs(xn)
n=0
while round(xn, 1)<=xk:
    while True:
        fx =(math.pow(-1,n)* math.pow(xn,2*n)) / (math.factorial(2*n))
        if abs(fx) <= Eps:
            n+=1
            print('|  %.2f  |  %.3f  |\t\t%d\t\t\t|\n------------------------' % (xn, fx, n))
            break
        else: 
            print('\n\nПоши неточные вычисления! \n Поставьте значение Eps побольше')
            exit()
    xn+=dx
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Очередной член ряда нетрудно рассчитать из предыдущего, не нужны ни степень, ни факториалы.

Точность Eps задаёт величину последнего слагаемого, когда оно становится малО, расчёт останавливается.

```
while xn <= xk:
    i = 0
    t = 1.0
    s = t
    while abs(t) > Eps:
        i += 2
        t *= -xn*xn / (i*(i-1))
        s += t
    print(xn, s) #тут уже печатайте, как надо
    xn+=dx

0 1.0
0.39269908169872414 0.9238795185084946
0.7853981633974483 0.7071068056832942
1.1780972450961724 0.3826848367714819
1.5707963267948966 -4.6476600836270853e-07
1.9634954084936207 -0.38268328945415253
2.356194490192345 -0.707104959107001
2.748893571891069 -0.923880028261737
3.141592653589793 -0.9999998647395553
```

Answer (score 1):

что-то вы перемудрили

задачу можно разбить на 2 части - вычислить ряд тейлора с заданной точность и вычислить этот ряд для ряда компонент

```
xs, xf, dx, eps = map(float, input("Введите xнач, xконеч, шаг, точность:"))
```

ну и сам ряд:

```
import math

def seq(x, eps):
    res = 0
    n = 0
    while True:
        value = (-1)**n * x**(2*n) / math.factorial(n)
        if abs(value) < eps:
            break
        res += value
        n += 1

    return res

print(seq(0.5, 0.01))
```

можно соптимизировать и сделать побыстрее:

```
def seq(x, eps):
    res = 0
    n = 0
    fact = 1
    v = 1
    while True:
        value = (1, -1)[n % 2] * v / fact
        if abs(value) < eps:
            break
        res += value
        n += 1
        fact *= n
        v *= x * x

    return res
```